# How are fabricated hadiths exposed?

Tags: uloom-al-hadith, ilm-ar-rijal

If a person with a seemingly good character falsified a hadith by writing the names of people who have passed away (in the chain before him), and if those people lived in the same area and lived at the same time as each other, how would authenticators realise that the hadith is fabricated?

Comment: If a narrator is trustworthy then you trust him\her to not fabricate a hadith.

Comment: What if they seem trustworthy but are a hypocrite?

Comment: There are signs of hypocrisy, and that's partly what being trustworthy means: you don't portray any signs of hypocrisy and are pious.

Comment: See for example [How can scholars of Jarh and ta'adil be certain about the identity of a narrator?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/49967/13438).